# How to read a .txt file and switch it structure to a 2D List

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I am so confused by these data structures, I just want to build a 2D type of structure to use the data.

Here is the txt file:

`COSTS A B C D E F G H I J SUPPLY
Source1 6 7 10 16 5 8 15 15 6 8 175 
Source2 10 14 8 17 13 9 18 20 9 7 200 
Source3 9 4 8 12 10 10 8 5 9 10 225 
Source4 12 8 9 10 6 15 4 9 7 0 300 
Source5 6 9 17 7 6 13 6 7 6 0 250 
Source6 9 10 9 13 9 8 9 3 4 9 100 
Source7 16 18 7 14 5 6 10 5 4 5 150 
Source8 7 5 8 3 8 5 10 8 8 14 300 
Source9 8 10 9 6 4 9 17 7 5 8 100 
Source10 5 8 4 5 7 14 6 3 13 9 200 
DEMAND 150 250 110 275 175 350 300 180 90 120`

Here is my code for now:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object[][] table = new Object[13][];
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    //sc.useDelimiter("\\Z"); 

    while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String sc1 = sc.nextLine();
        ArrayList<String> arrayList = 
            new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(sc1.split(" ")));

        System.out.println(arrayList);      
    }

    sc.close();
}
```

Comment: So what's not working here?

Comment: @SamzSakerz I want to build a 2D type of structure, like a 2D list or 2D arraylist

Comment: Check my answer and see if thats what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you want to load the data into `table = new Object[13][];` if so this is the code you need to use;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object[][] table = new Object[13][];
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = 0;
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String sc1 = sc.nextLine();
        table[i] = sc1.split(" ");
        i++;
    }
    sc.close();
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(table));
}
```

Basically I am just setting each index of the table to a String array that contains strings split by space.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. Just want to make sure "table" is a 2D list right?

Comment: Yes it is a 2D list, you can check here: https://www.journaldev.com/747/two-dimensional-array-java

Comment: Sorry, btw, do you know how to run the txt file in Eclipse? I think is in "run configuration",but what to write for running the argument?

Comment: No sorry, I don't use Eclipse and I use intelliJ. and I am not sure what you mean by run

Comment: No problem, right now I am running the code through command. I do "java myprogram < 10by10.txt" inorder to run the code with the txt file. I want to know how to run the argument txt file in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Using an array for this sort of thing can obviously be done but there is no easy way of knowing how many data lines are contained within a file you may be reading unless of course you know the specific data file you will be reading will always contain the same number of data lines. Many programmers will use an ArrayList or List Interface object to hold the data and if an array of type is still desired then the collection is converted to that type array.

> **Filling a 2D Array:**

First you need to know how many valid file lines of data are actually contained within the data file. The easiest way to do this is to do a two pass read. The first pass counts how many valid data lines there are in the file so that the Array size can be dimensioned properly and then the second pass fills the 2D Array. There are easy ways to determine the number of lines a file may contain but there is no easy ways to determine whether or not they are valid data lines (lines that actually contain data).

Your specific data file seems to contain three specific sections:

1. the ***Header*** section (first line of file);
2. the ***Raw Data*** section (file body);
3. and the ***Demand*** section (last line of file).

Retrieving each section into individual arrays can be beneficial so the code I provide below demonstrates how you can accomplish this. First you need to establish 3 class members variables, these will have global scope to the entire class:

```
String[] headerData;  // First data Line in file is the Header Information
Object[][] data;      // The 2D Object Array to hold raw File Data
int[] demandData;     // Last data line in file is the Demand Information
```

Now copy/paste the following method into your class:

```
private void readDataFile(String filePath) {
    Scanner sc;
    int maxColumns = 0;
    int validLines = 0;
    int endLine;
    try {
        sc = new Scanner(new File(filePath));
        String dataLine = "";
        // First Pass: 
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String fileLine = sc.nextLine().trim();
            /* Skip Blank Lines or lines that start with 
               a comment character (if any)... */
            if (fileLine.equals("") || fileLine.startsWith(";") || fileLine.startsWith("#")) {
                continue;
            }
            validLines++;  //This line must be a valid data line, so increment counter.
            dataLine = fileLine;
            if (validLines == 1) {
                // Get Header Information.
                headerData = dataLine.split("\\s+");  // Grab the Columns Header Names
                maxColumns = headerData.length;       // Get the number of data columns
            }
        }
        endLine = validLines;
        demandData = new int[endLine - 2];          // Initialize the demandData array
        data = new Object[endLine - 2][maxColumns]; // Initialize the data array 
        // Make sure the last line actually contains data
        if (dataLine.equals("")) {
            // No it doesn't so there is no DEMAND line.
            System.out.println("No DEMAND Data Available In File!");
            sc.close();
            return;
        }

        /* Fill the demandData int array with Integer data...
           The dataLine variable at this point will hold 
           the last valid file data line which happend to 
           be the Demand Line   */
        String[] dl = dataLine.split("\\s+"); // split the data line on 1 or more whitespaces.
        // Don't want the word "DEMAND" so we start from 1.
        for (int i = 1; i < dl.length; i++) {
            demandData[i-1] = Integer.parseInt(dl[i]);
        }

        // Second Pass (fill the data aray):
        sc = new Scanner(new File("MyDataFile.txt"));
        validLines = 0;
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String fileLine = sc.nextLine().trim();
            /* Skip Blank Lines or lines that start with 
               a comment character (if any)... */
            if (fileLine.equals("") || fileLine.startsWith(";") || fileLine.startsWith("#")) {
                continue;
            }
            validLines++;  //This line must be a valid data line, so increment counter.
            if (validLines == endLine) {
                break;
            }
            if (validLines == 1) { continue; }  // Skip the header line
            dl = fileLine.split("\\s+");        // split the data line on 1 or more whitespaces.
            for (int i = 0; i < dl.length; i++) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    data[validLines-2][i] = dl[i]; //String Object - Sources Name
                }
                else {
                    data[validLines-2][i] = Integer.parseInt(dl[i]); // Integer Object
                }
            }
        }
        sc.close();  /* Close the reader.
        Make sure the number of data rows equals the number 
        of Demand values otherwise inform of mismatch. */
        if (data.length != demandData.length) {
            System.out.println("Warning: There is missing DEMAND information (data mismatch)!\n"
                             + "There is no available Demand data for one of the Sources.");
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

And here is how you might use this method:

```
readDataFile("10by10.txt");

if (data != null) {
    // Header Information:
    System.out.println("Header Column Names:\n" + 
                 Arrays.toString(headerData) + "\n");

    // The Actual Data:
    System.out.println("File Data:");
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data[i]));
    }

    // The Demand Information:
    System.out.println("\nDemand Values For Each Row:\n" + 
                 Arrays.toString(demandData) + "\n");
}
```

And if you supply your example file data here is what would be displayed n the Console Window:

```
Header Column Names:
[COSTS, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, SUPPLY]

File Data:
[Source1, 6, 7, 10, 16, 5, 8, 15, 15, 6, 8, 175]
[Source2, 10, 14, 8, 17, 13, 9, 18, 20, 9, 7, 200]
[Source3, 9, 4, 8, 12, 10, 10, 8, 5, 9, 10, 225]
[Source4, 12, 8, 9, 10, 6, 15, 4, 9, 7, 0, 300]
[Source5, 6, 9, 17, 7, 6, 13, 6, 7, 6, 0, 250]
[Source6, 9, 10, 9, 13, 9, 8, 9, 3, 4, 9, 100]
[Source7, 16, 18, 7, 14, 5, 6, 10, 5, 4, 5, 150]
[Source8, 7, 5, 8, 3, 8, 5, 10, 8, 8, 14, 300]
[Source9, 8, 10, 9, 6, 4, 9, 17, 7, 5, 8, 100]
[Source10, 5, 8, 4, 5, 7, 14, 6, 3, 13, 9, 200]

Demand Values For Each Data Row:
[150, 250, 110, 275, 175, 350, 300, 180, 90, 120]
```

> **Filling a 2D List Interface:**

Here we do things a little differently and you'll see how much easier it can be. This time our **readDataFile()** method returns a 2D List Interface object of type String which we can easily manipulate to acquire the Header Column Names, the Raw Data, and the Demand Data values.

Here is the method:

```
 private List<List<String>> readDataFile(String filePath) {
    Scanner sc;
    List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        sc = new Scanner(new File(filePath));
        while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
            String fileLine = sc.nextLine().trim();
            /* Skip Blank Lines or lines that start with 
               a comment character (if any)... */
            if (fileLine.equals("") || fileLine.startsWith(";") || fileLine.startsWith("#")) {
                continue;
            }
            /* Valid data line we want...add it to the list.
               Here we split the data line into a String array
               then we use the Arrays.asList() method to convert
               it to a List then we add that List to our 2D List. 
               All done in one line of code.  */
            list.add(Arrays.asList(fileLine.split("\\s+")));
        }
        sc.close();     // Close the reader.
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    return list;
}
```

And to use this method against your example data file:

```
// Read the file data and place it all into a 2D List
List<List<String>> list = readDataFile("10by10.txt");

// Get the Header Column Names from first ArrayList
String[] headerData = list.get(0).toArray(new String[0]);   

// The 2D Object Array to hold raw File Data
Object[][] data = new Object[list.size() - 2][headerData.length];      
for(int i = 1; i < list.size() - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < list.get(i).size(); j++) {
        if (j == 0) {
            data[i - 1][j] = list.get(i).get(j);
        }
        else {
            data[i - 1][j] = Integer.parseInt(list.get(i).get(j));
        }
    }
}

// Last data line in file is the DEMAND Values
String[] tmp = list.get(list.size() - 1).toArray(new String[0]);
int[] demandData = new int[tmp.length - 1];
for (int i = 1; i < tmp.length; i++) {
    demandData[i - 1] = Integer.parseInt(tmp[i]);
}

if (data != null) {
    // Header Information:
    System.out.println("Header Column Names:\n"
            + Arrays.toString(headerData) + "\n");

    // The Actual Data:
    System.out.println("File Data:");
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data[i]));
    }

    // The Demand Information:
    System.out.println("\nDemand Values For Each Row:\n"
            + Arrays.toString(demandData) + "\n");
}
```

The output to console window will be the same as previously shown above.